# Reading html list items from android java code

Tags: java, android, html, listview, html-lists

As I explained in title, I found this website (rpg.rem.uz) that uses a list.
I wanted to read the title of each list item programmatically in my android java code. I need it to populate a listview in the same way that list is populated.

please let me know if it is possible and how to do that.

thanks in advance

**EDIT**
I tried using Jsoup but I get an Handshake failed exception

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jsoup library for parsing HTML.
Read doc and its examples:
https://jsoup.org

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you can ([android.text.Html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html)), but practically don't.

A WebView ([android.webkit.WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)) could satisfy your need, but you better think about some APIs for you site, JSON is what you need

Comment: errrr... the site is not mine

Comment: Thus "I have this website" maybe is not the appropriate spec.. anyway, good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this may help you. you need to set up this [library](https://jsoup.org/) **first** to your project then use the code below :

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");//pass your list id
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("li");
for (Element list: lists) {
  String linkText = link.text();
}
```

**OR**

You can direct load your html from your url -:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("li");
```

Just read the documentation from this [link](https://jsoup.org/). You can also see some examples [here](https://try.jsoup.org/~LGB7rk_atM2roavV0d-czMt3J_g)

Comment: what is input.html?

Comment: your html file name

Comment: please accept this answer if this this answer help you @GiocatoreDentro by click on tick

Comment: I want to test it first. android studio crashes a lot recently. Once I tried it I'll accept your answer, 'kay?

Comment: Okay @GiocatoreDentro